# Medieval England story - "Step in, Step Inn", "Good Morning, Good Knight"

Tags: identification-request

I remember reading a book during my school days. There was a story which was based during some war in medieval England I believe. There was an Inn in the story named Step Inn. Where the owner of the Inn used to welcome the guests with the pun

> 'Step in, Step Inn.'

He also used to used all over the story where once a knight entered in his Inn and he greeted him with,

> 'Good Morning, Good Knight.'

Does anyone know which story this is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is ***Sir Nobonk and the terrible, awful, dreadful, naughty, nasty Dragon*** (1982) by **Spike Milligan** (published by M. & J. Hobbs, with illustrations by Carol Baker).

Here's the bit you remembered:

> As the Dragon Hunters trekked through the forests of Cornwall they came to the Way Inn.
>
> ‘Let’s stay here for the night,’ said Sir Nobonk.
>
> The landlord was Mr Clanger. ‘That name rings a bell,’ said Big Bill (JOKE).
>
> For dinner Big Bill and Little Willy had purple pork chops and pink peas, but Sir Nobonk was a vegetarian and had roast chestnuts, chips and Smarties.
>
> Next day the landlord brought him breakfast in bed.
>
> ‘Good morning, good Knight,’ he said.
>
> ‘Good morning good-night?’ That was a short day, thought Sir Nobonk. ([page 7](https://archive.org/details/sirnobonkterribl0000mill/page/n9/mode/2up))

Note that the inn with the punny name is the "Way Inn", not the "Step Inn".